# Build Associations Rails 3.1

Tags: model, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

Anytime I create a user and log in this exception is thrown on the redirect: `Couldn't find User without an ID`.

I have a `has_many` association like so:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tags
belongs_to :user

attr_accessible :title, :description, :content, :tags_attributes

accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda {|attrs| attrs.all? {|key, value| value.blank?}}

end
```

followed by:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :posts
attr_accessible :codename, :password, :password_confirmation

end
```

There is a third model 'Tags' which has a `belongs_to post` but that does not appear to be causing the problem. There is also a SessionsController with `new`,`create`, and `destroy` actions (code below).

The `find_user` method is run only on the new and create actions in the PostsController

```
before_filter :find_user

def find_user
 @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end


def new
 @post = @user.posts.build(tags: Tag.new)
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html 
  end
end

def create
 @post = @user.posts.build(params[:post])
 @tags = @post.tags.build(params[:tags])
  respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
  else
    format.html { render action: :new }
  end
 end
end
```

and the User.authenticate method / SessionsController `create` action

```
def self.authenticate(codename, password)
 user = User.find_by_codename(codename)
  unless user && user.authenticate(password)
   raise "You are not who you say you are."
  end
 user
end

def create
 session[:user_id] = User.authenticate(params[:codename], params[:password]).id 
 redirect_to action: session[:intended_action], controller: session[:intended_controller], success: "You're In!"
end
```

Comment: Looks like params[:id] is empty, but it should point to some user.  Also, when preparing post, you should use tags association, not tag.

Comment: thanks, can you explain why the plural and not the singular? Is it because it is the child?

Comment: Because you declared `has_many :tags` in `Post` model you should use `post.tags`.

Comment: so is the solution for `new` and `create` actions `@post= @user.post.tags.build()` in your view?

Comment: Once you have `@user` loaded, you can build post using `@post = @user.posts.build` and after that `@post.tags.build`. Probably, you should move these preparations into a `Post` model.

Comment: your comments have been very helpful; I will try to use a named scope inside the model to tidy up the controller. However there appears to be a problem with my SessionsController as well.

Comment: Please show `User.authenticate` method.  Looks like it should return user.id on success login.

Comment: @taro added methods. thanks for being patient and reviewing this.

Comment: Ok, you store id of authenticated user in session, so you should be alble load logged in user using `User.find(session[:user_id])`.

Comment: @taro solved. please make this an answer so you can get credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be easy - you storing id of authenticated User in session object, but trying to fetch user using `params[:user_id]` instead of `session[:user_id]`